# ListView Not Scrolling Inside Column in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having trouble making a ListView scrollable within a Column in Flutter. The ListView displays correctly, but I cannot scroll through the items. I've tried several variations to extend the ListView to the bottom of the screen while keeping it scrollable and avoiding the "Bottom overflowed by x pixels" error, but none of my attempts have been successful.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(bottom: 8.0, start: 8.0, end: 8.0, top: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ...,
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                  ...,
                  Flexible(
                     fit: FlexFit.loose,
                     child: ListView.builder(
                       itemCount: ...
                       shrinkWrap: true,
                       itemBuilder: ....,
                  ),
              ],
            ),
           ],
         ),
         ...,
    ],
  ),
)
```

I've set mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min for the Column and used Flexible with FlexFit.loose for the ListView.builder in an attempt to make it scrollable. However, the ListView doesn't scroll, and I'm trying to avoid the overflow error while ensuring the list extends to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Wrap your Listview with Expand and give physics it will work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `ListView` with `Expanded` widget instead of `Flexible` widget and you can scroll it.

```
children: <Widget>[
// Other widgets before ListView
    Expanded( // Wrap with Expanded
       child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: ...,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: ...,
           ),
      ),
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.

```
Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: 100,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text('Your Other Widget If you want'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 100,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Text(index.toString());
            },
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: 100,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Text('Your Other Widget If you want'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```